# Code first deploy on production

Tags: entity-framework, deployment, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have copy of prod DB and code on my DEV PC.

On production I saw in system tables that 8 migrations records exist in _MigrationHistory. (The first version of the code and deploy was written by another person).

I need to add few new tables and code for work with them - models and controller. I can add new models for new tables and code for controller.

On the DEV PC I can start command

> add-migration myNewMigration

and

> update-database with option "-script"

and without it to get tables in my DEV DB and script to execute on Production.

For deploy I need to copy content on bin folder and new views on Prod and to run SQL script to create new tables in DB.

I was wondering is that enough because at the moment I see records for all migrations in my DEV environment corresponding records in Production environment  in system tables - _MigrationHistory.

If I only run the SQL script on PROD may be new record for this operation will not appear in _MigrationHistory. So could be that a reason to get error that model is different and to have any problem after deploy.

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question, but not well articulated.

Comment: Have a look at how I formatted your question.  It makes it much easier to understand the problem.  I also cleaned up some English mistakes, but that is not really a problem.  Clean formatting is the important change.

Comment: Thank you Eric - your remark for formatting is absolutely reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before making changes to the production database, ensure you have a complete backup.

> I was wondering is that enough because at the moment I see records for all migrations in my Dev environment corresponding records in Production environment in system tables - _MigrationHistory

If you ran the code in your development environment, it will apply your explicit migrations.

If I understand your comment correctly, you see the same migrations in DEV and in PROD.  If that is accurate, then PROD may be up-to-date.

Look in your Migrations folder in your project.  There you will see a complete list of migrations, each one in its own .cs file (plus related .Designer.cs and .resx files).  Compare what you see there to the list of migrations in __MigrationHistory in DEV and in PROD to understand the full set of migrations, and where they have been applied.

> If I only run sql script on Prod may be new record for this operation will not appear in _MigrationHistory

Have a look at your migration scripts.  They insert the appropriate entry into __MigrationHistory where they are run (including in production).  Here's an edited example from one of my projects:

> INSERT [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]([MigrationId], [ContextKey], [Model], [ProductVersion])
>   VALUES (N'201409082209285_VDisposer', N'Survey.Model.Migrations.MembershipConfiguration.MembershipConfiguration',  0x1F8B0800000...1A0200 , N'6.1.1-30610')
>
> So could be that a reason to get error that model is different and to have any problem after deploy

If you are having an error that the model does not match the database, there is another reason.

Here's what I suggest to narrow down the differences:

1. Backup your production database.
2. Restore it in your DEV environment (use a name different than your usual DEV database, or backup your DEV database first.  If using a different name, remember to temporarily change web.config to the new database).
3. Create a new migration.
4. Look at the code generated for the new migration.  It will point out differences between what is in PROD and the state that DEV is in.

Remember to undo changes to your web.config after you are done.

Comment: So if I understand you right the steps are following: Create on dev Models and add migration plus database-update After that deploy bin and views and run scripts on production The script will add needed record in _MigrationHistory. So this should be enough for deploy on Production. If I run sql script on dev too I can skip update-database for dev - isnt it?

Comment: Sounds correct.  Note that if you run the scripts in DEV, migrations will run but do nothing when the app starts (assuming you have it configured to apply migrations) because it finds the entries in __MigrationHistory.  You *could* also skip the step of creating scripts and just allow the app to automatically update PROD, but I suggest maintaining control by using scripts as you are currently.